# Why is resource id different at runtime than in editor?

Tags: hover, resource-id

Using Android Studio 4.1

I have a layout with a toolbar.  I refer to the toolbar resource id in Java as `R.id.mytoolbar` for example.  In the Java editor, when I hover over the `R.id.mytoolbar` reference, the popup displays something like:

`public static final int mytoolbar = 1000067`

I am wondering what that means, particularly the value 1000067.  At runtime, the value of R.id.mytoolbar is a different integer, in particular: 2131296664 (hex 7f090198).